# Filling each element of a list

Tags: r, list, loops, lapply

I am trying to fill each element of a list using the function `rmultinom`:

```
# probabilities of group membership for 3 observations to be generated
probs = data.frame("grp1"=c(.1, .9, 0), "grp2"=c(.2, .2, .6), "grp3"=c(.3,.1,.6))
n = length(probs)

# generate a categorical variable
cat.var = vector("list", n)   # create vector of lists for each observation's indicators
for (j in 1:n)  cat.var[[j]] = rmultinom(1, 1, probs[j,])

# everything is NULL
cat.var

# yet the below works...
cat.var[[1]] = rmultinom(1, 1, probs[1,])
cat.var[[2]] = rmultinom(1, 1, probs[2,])
cat.var[[3]] = rmultinom(1, 1, probs[3,])
```

My questions are:

1. What is wrong with the above?
2. Is there a better way to achieve the desired result, for example using `lapply`? When I tried `lapply`, I wasn't sure how to have the `FUN` argument differ for each element of the list (i.e., that `cat.var[[j]]` should be assigned a value generated by `rmultinom(1, 1, probs[j,])`).

Comment: `obs` is given where??

Comment: Sorry! I've edited it.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that is the issue.

Comment: added an example on the `lapply` part of the question as well. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the `obs` in the `for(i in 1:obs)` to `for(i in 1:n)` and setting a `seed`,

```
# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(113)
for (j in 1:n)  cat.var[[j]] = rmultinom(1, 1, probs[j,])
```

I get:

```
cat.var
    [[1]]
     [,1]
grp1    0
grp2    1
grp3    0

[[2]]
     [,1]
grp1    0
grp2    1
grp3    0

[[3]]
     [,1]
grp1    0
grp2    1
grp3    0
```

And writing it with `lapply` we create a secondary function with an `x` index to iterate through `probs`

```
set.seed(113)

lstyle = function(x, n, size, prob){
  rmultinom(n, size, probs[x,])
}

lapply(X = 1:n, FUN = lstyle, n = 1, size = 1, prob = probs)
```

And we get:

```
[[1]]
     [,1]
grp1    0
grp2    1
grp3    0

[[2]]
     [,1]
grp1    0
grp2    1
grp3    0

[[3]]
     [,1]
grp1    0
grp2    1
grp3    0
```

Comment: Darn. Sorry. I need to try again to recreate my problem in a short example.